# How to count the number of same values in php or mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
p1  p2  p3  p4  p5          p6           p7       p8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1414    1414    1417    1417    1422,1421   1422,1421   1422,1421     1422,1421
```

The above table has 8 columns in which the adjacent columns having same values. How to count the number of columns based on the column values in php or in mysql..

For Eg :

```
for 1414---values are p1,p2 and count is 2

 for 1422,1421--- values are p5,p6,p7,p8 and count is 4.
```

Can any one help me in this..

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [period] => p1
            [subject] => 1434
            [nop] => 1
        )

```
<b>
    **[1] => Array
    (
        [period] => p2
        [subject] => 1440,1439
        [nop] => 1
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [period] => p2,p3
        [subject] => 1440,1439
        [nop] => 2
    )**
</b>

[3] => Array
    (
        [period] => p2,p3,p4
        [subject] => 1440,1439
        [nop] => 3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [period] => p5
        [subject] => 1442
        [nop] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [period] => p6
        [subject] => 1442
        [nop] => 1
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [period] => p7
        [subject] => 1442
        [nop] => 1
    )
```

)

I have got the above array.. how to remove the above highlighted values in the above array from it.

Comment: r u selecting one row each time?

Comment: The above values for the columns are not at all constant evrytime. The values will be changing all the time. I need to concat the column names along with the count of columns that have same values..

Comment: if i use array_unique for the above array i m getting only the one value in array.. how do remove array[1] and array[2] from the above pasted output in php. can anyone give reply for this..

Answer (score 0):

suppose your $row has reesult of table

```
$your_val = '1414'; // for eg 1414

$result_col = ""; // will contain you columns
$result_count = 0;  // will contain your count

// $row has the each column value when you fetch from database eg $row['p1'] = 1414
foreach($row as $key=>$val)  
{
   if($val==$your_val)
   {
     $result_count += 1;

     if($result_text=="")
     {
      $result_col = $key;
     }
     else
     {
       $result_col = $result_col.",".$key;
     }
   }
}

echo "values are ".$result_col." and count is ".$result_count; // output
```

Comment: $your_val = '1414'; I cant hardcore the values like this since the values will be changing all the time. can i have any other solution for this..

Comment: how you change the value. r u getting this by get/post?

Comment: I dnt get that values in get/post. i get those values from backend table itself.

Comment: then get value from your table as required and run above code for each your value. i mean to say assign each value in `$your_val` and run given code for it.

Comment: i am geeting the values for p1,p2 etc as for($m=1;$m<=$noofperiods;$m++)
        {
            $peri = 'p'.$m; }  how to put that in ur given code // $row has the each column value when you fetch from database eg $row['p1'] = 1414
foreach($row as $key=>$val)  
{

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with MySQL:

```
SELECT 
IF(p1='1414',1,0) + IF(p2='1414',1,0)+ IF(p3='1414',1,0) + IF(p4='1414',1,0) + IF(p5='1414',1,0) + IF(p6='1414',1,0) + IF(p7='1414',1,0) + IF(p8='1414',1,0) AS cnt
FROM your_table;
```

If you are using PHP to access the databasem, you can replace the '1414' with a variable to count the occurences of the variable's value.